# Ajax: Pass Model List to Controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, model

I have a view that takes a list of a model as the Model, so

```
 @model List<Collections.Models.Status>
```

I want to pass this list as the data for an Ajax call, but I keep getting "System.Collections.Generic.List[Collections.Models.Status]" instead of the values in the model.

Here's the Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Update",
        data: JSON.stringify(@Model),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (responseJSON) {
            if (responseJSON.message == 'success') {
                alert('here');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            showModal("Error: " + error.message);
        }
    });
```

Which translates in the debugger to:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Update",
        data: JSON.stringify(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Collections.Models.CollectionStatus]),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (responseJSON) {
            if (responseJSON.message == 'success') {
                alert('here');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            showModal("Error: " + error.message);
        }
    });
```

How do I pass the actual values of the list instead of System.Collections.Generic.List[Collections.Models.Status]?

I've tried @Model.ToList(), @Html.Raw(Model), neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

set contentType property to application/json.
and use below code to set data property

```
data: JSON.stringify({'your controllers parameter name': '@Model'})
```

Comment: That executed the call, but it didn't pass the values, I got a count = 0 in the controller when I checked the passed in parameter.